# exibir lista de dependentes por usuario no laravel 6

Tags: laravel, view, relacionamento

Eu tenho minha página principal "home" com rota que é exibida após o login.

Então essa "**home.blade.php**" exibe uma página com os dados do usuário logado.

Criei uma tabela "dependentes", fiz o relacionamento entre essa tabela e a tabela "users", é um relacionamento **OneToMany**, onde um usuário possui "N" dependentes.

Ao logar eu queria exibir uma lista de dependentes e devo estar fazendo errado.

Tenho a seguinte função no meu controler **HomeControler** :

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
// OUTRAS FUNÇÕES OMITIDAS

 public function home(AQUI COMO COLOCO ID DO USUARIO LOGADO?)
{
    $user = User::where('id',$id)-> first();
    $dependentes = $user->dependentes()->get();
    return view('auth.home');
}
```

Se estiver correta a função acima, como eu coloco na pagina Home pra listar os dependentes?
Seria assim?

```
<div class="pmo-block pmo-items hidden-xs">
         <h2>Dependentes</h2>
         <div class="pmob-body">
   @foreach ($dependentes as $dependente)
             <div class="row">
            <a href="" class="col-xs-2">
            <img class="img-circle" src="/bs3/img/demo/profile-pics/1.jpg" alt="">
            </a>    
           </div>
   @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz assim que vai funcionar:

no seu método home:

```
 public function home()
    {
       $dependentes =  Auth::user()->dependentes()->get();
       return view('auth.home',compact('dependentes')); // essa linha vai pra View que 
       //você quer que é a HOME e ainda passa a variáver $dependentes. Faça um Foreach e 
       //seja feliz
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Gratidão